# Code Metrics feature is missing in VS2015 Enterprise Preview 4

Tags: code-metrics, visual-studio-2015

The Code Metrics feature is missing in VS2015 Enterprise Preview 4

It's no longer under the Analyze menu of Visual Studio.

Where can I find this feature?

Comment: Notice you can still use the NDepend code metrics feature integrated in VS 2015  http://www.ndepend.com/docs/code-metrics    ; http://www.ndepend.com/docs/treemap-visualization-of-code-metrics